# Sort original table in descending order

Tags: jquery, datatables

All,
I'm using the following theme which utilizes the datatable plugin:

http://revaxarts-themes.com/whitelabel/datatable.html

Things work great except for one thing. I'm trying to sort my table in descending order on the first column when it loads. Currently it only sorts it in Ascending order. Here is a JS Fiddle that has the JS file that is included in theme:

http://jsfiddle.net/nHejP/

I found this line in there (line 1077 on that):

```
/*
* Variable: aaSorting
* Purpose:  Sorting information
* Scope:    jQuery.dataTable.classSettings
* Notes:    Index 0 - column number
*           Index 1 - current sorting direction
*           Index 2 - index of asSorting for this column
*/
this.aaSorting = [ [0, 'asc', 0] ];
```

I changed this to the following value:

```
this.aaSorting = [ [0, 'desc', 0] ];
```

This still sorts my initial column in ascending order. Is there another value that I have to set?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked through the [docs of datatable here](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html). Instead of modifying the original sourcecode, you should pass in the sort order when you first initialize datatable.

You can pass in the sort order using the `aaSorting` property like so

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]]
    } );
} );
```

[**jsFiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/uHHGw/)

Comment: Thanks but when I do that, I get the following alert: DataTables warning (table id='feedback_entries'): Cannot reinitialise DataTable. To retreive the DataTables object for this table, please pass either no arguments to the dataTable() function or set bRetrieve to true. Alternatively, to destroy the old table and create a new one, set bDestroy to true (note that a lot of changes to the configuration can be made through the API which is usually much faster).

Comment: That means its been initalized somewhere else in your page before. Find where its been initilized and modified or add the aaSorting property there